# what communication technology should i use to create my app?

Tags: java, sockets

hello
As a project I've been asked to write using java my own dropbox. My program will have, like the original dropbox a listener (using nio2-already wrote) to a specific folder and will need to upload the files to a remote server. The server will also have a simple interface that I'm leaving to the end. I can every technology i want. we learned hibernate (because i need to save the data in mySQL DB). We also learned sockets, servlets, rest, and comet.

i'm a little confused of how to do the communication part of my program. i can use socket but it's very low level and i was searching for a more faster high level and easier technology. I read so much and saw so many terms such as Apache Mina, Netty,RMI...

i need something simple with allot of FAQ and examples online that will support:

1. a multi thread server application.
2. i don't care if it's on HTTP...
3. easy to implement and transfer data between several clients and a server.
4. a simple way that if a file changes the server will notify the client.

tnx allot

Answer (score 0):

Enter [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) with servlets. As for the notification goes. You may embed the container in the client and have the server push the update notification.

Comment: but what will the client use? socket?

Comment: You're right! what about HttpClient :) http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/

Comment: can i use it to send big files?